# function with a generic Type and using string as a default parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a function with an object as an input that is generic, I want to provide a default implementation by making the generic `T` a string and provide the needed arguments with default values that uses a string instead

```
type Props<T> = {
  items: T[];
  renderItem: (item: T) => JSX.Element;
};

const defaultRenderItem = (item: string) => item;
const defaultItems = ['1', '2'];

function render<T>({ items = defaultItems, renderItem = defaultRenderItem }: Props<T>) {
  return items.map(renderItem);
}
```

you can check a running example of this code [over here](https://codesandbox.io/s/young-grass-z9drn?file=/index.ts)

the problem is that typescript is complaining that `'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'string'.ts(2322)`

I do understand typescript's concern, can somebody point me or provide an alternative on how I can achieve the same result without the error

Comment: Can I assume you want to be able to call `render({})`?  Or do you need to write `render({items: undefined, renderItem: undefined})` if you want the defaults?

Comment: @jcalz yes you can assume that I want to be able to call `render({})`

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) your way out of the error in the implementation side of the function, but I presume you want to prevent someone from *calling* things like:

```
render({ renderItem: (x: number) => x - 2 });
```

This would cause a runtime error, but the compiler would happily infer `number` for `T` and pretend everything is fine.

---

To fix that, I think maybe we should give up on using default values in the call signature itself and use [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) to represent the two distinct call cases: if you pass an incomplete `Props`, then it must be a `Props<string>`.  Otherwise, if you pass a complete `Props`, you can use any generic type you'd like as long as it matches.  We'll deal with default values inside the implementation.  Which might look like this:

```
function render(stringProps: Partial<Props<string>>): string[];
function render<T>(otherProps: Props<T>): T[];
function render(props: Partial<Props<any>>) {
    const items = props.items || defaultItems;
    const renderItem = props.renderItem || defaultRenderItem;
    return items.map(renderItem);
}
```

Using `Partial<Props<any>>` inside the implementation is similar to using a type assertion, in that the compiler will not complain about `props.items || defaultItems` not being a `T[]`, since it will definitely be an `any[]`.  Implementations of overloads are not very strongly checked, so we have to be careful.

Anyway, then you'd use it like this, presumably as desired:

```
// first overload, Partial<Props<string>> 
const a = render({}); // string[]
const b = render({ renderItem: x => x.toUpperCase() }); // okay, x must be string
// second overload, Props<T> for generic <T>
const c = render({ items: [1, 2, 3], renderItem: x => x - 2 }); // okay, d is number[]

// errors
const d = render<number>({}); // error! {} is not a Props<number>
const e = render({ renderItem: (x: number) => x - 2 }); // error! if you leave out a property, it must be string-typed 
const f = render({ items: [1, 2, 3], renderItem: (x: string) => x.toUpperCase() }); // error! mismatch types
```

The compiler will now yell at you if you try to call `render()` with something incomplete unless that incomplete thing is consistent with choosing `string` as `T` in the generic version.  Hopefully this gives you enough to work with.  Good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.2#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgezAZwDwBUB8UC8UDeAUFCVAJbAQC2yAXFOgNoC6A3MaXBAHYAmEcAJKUq9ABQVq9dAEpc2dOwC+7QgGME3ZMCj8AZgEMArgBtgAJR78hI3FAkj62uGW4BzOTmySq7DVp19YzNhamQ7RgByAEZIgBooSIAmSLZCQj0jbjVgMk0oLj4BMWdXN3gkOlgDOFyDE1QKlFRS90xMGSdgF3cWdkzs3PzC6wxMMQRgAAsBJqq5sc6GPoysnLzuAqtisEQUehgauoaFg24QdrkiUih-bXIRcLxdyoA6H3CAH0-dCENTYChGisKAcEh3HQjARAuwvFCvKE2ahQb6-f5mSxFJG+MFbYBGOCbD6vKgGMBiRFAmTKdIAelpUD0ZDg9wQADcBCYEAZeAlDrUyPVGns0K03O1QRCoAY7IixPglNSoPSoGKWOpNPcAEay7ZweVbLFA+gAD3kUBNr2ACAAqmBIHAAMIGZAQMRyRUglUIADWBhACTNVCM2ugYsIKtd-l4UHZnO5vNgIrGjIQcCgbh4AjIaigYw1AVuuqxBo+9EY0QSSQSAGZmAlKY4LeazQBaKBJKCe5UM33+hIxsjhbhGKhagTqiMMgSIFkF+4xvCI1AjscCcYKpUqmdpgCEBCU5GHk2lScqK9H47gmHnOmgS71BsbUnsJvoq6vnmwbY7Xa307gWd9zIPQoBABAjCgEwIAMDlYyMHQZThARQASCgoGDUNVW6MpW1ASAY1vRli2sUtHnLSsO1retDWsY1Xy6HoPBbK1bXtARnVdd0-y9ACgIwodSWANQpigfCIGQdJCCAA)